# Change ImageButton Size by Dragging

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, button

I am making a lot of ImageButtons where the image aspect does not matter.  That is, I do not care if it is stretched.  They are invisible buttons to go on top of a background.

Is there an easy way to layout and stretch my ImageButtons through the graphical editor?  I do not want to have to test out each possible padding in my xml.  I just want to stretch the sides of the images as though it were an Office Word.

Ask if clarification is needed, please.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure to understand your question, but you can use  android:scaleType="fitXY" to stretch your images, and android:adjustViewBounds="true" to have them adjust their bounds due to scaling.

Comment: Does not let me adjust bounds in the graphical layout even with these settings.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not 100% sure about your question neither. If you meant you want to do it in IDE, eclipse allows you to define the button with dragging.